# Manual PDF no longer created with package check?

Tags: r, documentation, rstudio, documentation-generation

I do all my package development with the build environment in RStudio (0.99.891). Historically, when I would run a package check, the resulting `package.Rcheck` directory would have a `package-manual.pdf` file, but within the past few months whenever I check a package the manual PDF no longer appears in my directory. I have not changed any of my check package options but continue to use `--as-cran`.

It seems RStudio has not updated their documentation yet online for [how to customize build options](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200486518-Customizing-Package-Build-Options) so that's no help. After seeing this question on SO: [After running R CMD Check, the mypackage.Rcheck directory with PDF manual disappeared](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26979968/after-running-r-cmd-check-the-mypackage-rcheck-directory-with-pdf-manual-disapp), I double checked and "Cleanup output after successful R CMD Check" is unchecked.

In RStudio's outdated documentation they describe a `--no-manual` option, but maybe this is now the default?

How can I get the manual back? I like to look it over before submitting to CRAN to make sure there are no issues.

Comment: I'll agree that the why is not programming but how to get the PDF back I think is quite appropriate.

Comment: I removed the pondering about why they did this and now more explicitly ask how to get it back.

Comment: I've not heard anything about "manuals" using that exact term as a requirement for CRAN. Are you sure you are not thinking of help page Index or a vignette?

Comment: If you look at the page on CRAN for any package you'll see a link to a "Reference manual". This pdf  used to be created when you checked the contents but it no longer is

Comment: That `--no-manual` text is not actually part of RStudio but is rather the output when you run `R CMD check --help` at a system command line. Is it possible you are affected by this NEWS item in version 3.2.0? "Building the manuals now requires texi2any from texinfo 5.1 or later. CRAN binary builds include the manuals, but by default builds from source will not, and they will be accessed from CRAN. See the comments in ‘src/gnuwin32/MkRules.dist’ for how to specify the location of texi2any."

Comment: That looks exactly like my problem! Thanks 42. Please post as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That `--no-manual` text is not actually part of RStudio but is rather the output when you run `R CMD check --help` at a system command line. Is it possible you are affected by this NEWS item in version 3.2.0?

> "Building the manuals now requires texi2any from texinfo 5.1 or later. CRAN binary builds include the manuals, but by default builds from source will not, and they will be accessed from CRAN. See the comments in ‘src/gnuwin32/MkRules.dist’ for how to specify the location of texi2any."

Comment: For the Mac OSX tarball of R, the comments are:

for texinfo >= 5.1. If the texinfo files are installed at /packages/texinfo,
TEXI2ANY = /path/to/perl -I/packages/texinfo /packages/texinfo/texi2any
if you do not have texinfo (default),
TEXI2ANY = missing

Answer (score 1):

This is not a solution to the problem but an alternative. Installing and configuring the texi2any localization is a bit tricky, so I solved it writting the manual directly from the windows shell as follows:

> R CMD Rd2pdf file_location

where file_location is the path of the folder that contents all files of the package, as DESCRIPTION, man folder, etc.

Comment: Note that before of that you need to install pdfLateX (e.g., from here https://miktex.org/howto/install-miktex) and allow R to run from the windows shell: Control panel > security and system > system>
Advanced system configuration > environment variables.
Click on path and edit:
Adding the path to R (e.g., C: \ Program Files \ R \ R-3.0.2 \ bin \ x64)